# scalar object requires one element in initializer

Tags: c, pointers

Why when I want to initialize the following vector of `uint8_t`

```
uint8_t *mmac_source1 = { 0x01, 0x80, 0xc2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
```

I get this error

```
Error: scalar object 'mmac_source1' requires one element in initializer
```

But when I am using this :

```
uint8_t mmac_source1[6] = { 0x01, 0x80, 0xc2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
```

it's working fine.

Comment: uint8_t mmac_source1[] = { 0x01, 0x80, 0xc2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 }; Should give you the advantages of the both worlds - you can write the initializer and you don't have to specify the size.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
uint8_t *mmac_source1 = { 0x01, 0x80, 0xc2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
```

Here you don't memory allocated to the pointer.
`mmac_source1` just acts as a place holder wherein you can store an address.

```
uint8_t mmac_source1[6] = { 0x01, 0x80, 0xc2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };
```

Here you have an array where in your compiler allocates `sizof(uint8_t)*6` bytes.

Comment: * 16, why? Did you mean * 6?

Comment: it's 6 bytes, it was a typo

Answer (score 5):

In many instances a pointer is interchangable with an array. More formally it can be said that the first element of an array *decays* to a pointer.

But there are exceptions and the one you cite in your question is one of them: `uint8_t *mmac_source1 = { 0x01, 0x80, 0xc2, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 };` is not syntatically valid. Conceptually you are allocating, in your second case, the array on the stack. Using a pointer in that instance doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

The rvalue expected for a pointer initialization is a memory address.

As in the case of arrays, the compiler allows the special case that we want to initialize the content at which the pointer points with constants at the same moment the pointer is declared:

```
char * str = "hello"; // what succeeds the equal to is the rvalue.
```

The above statement is similar to

```
char str[] = "hello";
```

The next question is if we are allowed to do the following :

```
int* v = 2;
```

Yes we are but at our own risk. The compiler will initially come with
an error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘int*’ [-fpermissive]
```

Here the compiler considered the rvalue as merely an integer where what it expected was a memory location say for example **&a** or so. At the same time
it provided an option **fpermissive** to **overrride** its assumption whereby
we can force the rvalue to look like a memory address.**fpermissive** flag
downgrades some diagnostics about nonconformant code from *errors to warnings*. So when compiling, I did

g++ -fpermissive intpointerexample.cpp -o intpointerexample

Eventually on executing intpointerexample, I encountered a segmentation fault because I might have attempted to access memory the program does not have rights to.